# Migrate Blog comments to Wordpress + Disqus

Tags: php, wordpress, disqus

I am currently moving my custom blog from (www.danvega.org/blog) to Wordpress (http://threaldanvega.com) and I also am in the process of moving my comments over to Disqus. All of my posts are migrated and the Disqus plugin is installed and operational. Any new comments on my blog work just fine but moving all of my old comments over is where I am having the problem.

I ran the import and it seems all of comments have been imported (I did this a few days ago)

[image]

I also can view the comments tab and see all of the comments I imported in the approved status. The links to the post on my site all work fine as well.

[image]

The problem is none of the comments show up on the page. This is the link to the 1st item in that screenshot http://therealdanvega.com/blog/2010/6/29/reversing-words-in-a-string#comment-1716793155

I also login to the wordpress admin > comments and I don't see any of the comments there. Again everything works normal for new comments but old comments aren't migrating. What am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did a similar migration. It may be a problem with the unique `disqusIdentifier` that disqus uses to group comments on a specific post. Check to make sure that your historical comments have the same `disqusIdentifier` as a new comment has for the same post.

For reference, any old comments on [this post](http://therealdanvega.com/blog/2010/06/29/reversing-words-in-a-string) should have a `disqusIdentifier` of 804.

Along with the identifier, also verify that the `disqusShortname` is the same for new and old comments.

Comment: So I exported the data out to take a close look. This is the first comment from the screen shot.

https://gist.github.com/cfaddict/18f565817e3b53dc59b7

And from everything I can see it matches up to the correct thread just fine.

https://gist.github.com/cfaddict/42351666b84c83875cee

Comment: It looks like the comment keys off of the dsq:id -> back to the thread and that thread URL is correct.

Comment: Have you looked into the solutions on this page: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/960360-syncing-with-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be an option for some people but this is how I "fixed" this. Since this was a new domain name and I have never used Disqus before I decided to take this route. I blew away the Disqus site in my admin and removed the Disqus plugin. I then wrote a script to migrate from my old mysql db to the new wordpres.wp_comments table. Now that I had all of comments in wordpress I created a new Disqus site and installed the plugin in wordpress. Now to move my data over to Disqus I simply exported it using tools > export

[image]

Then I went back over to Disqus and imported that file. After a few minutes everything was working fine.